# The final local variable cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type java

Tags: java, android, multithreading, list

I have created class `childList` that implements an interface `GetChildList`` like below:

```
    package com.example.hakslogin;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.example.hakslogin.GetChildList;
import com.example.hakslogin.HandleJSON;

public class childList implements GetChildList
{
    private HandleJSON obj;
    public String urlString = "http://192.168.x.xx:xxxx/getdb";
    public void callFetchJSONChild(){
        HandleJSON obj = new HandleJSON(urlString);
        List<String> list = obj.fetchJSONChild(this);
   }
    @Override
    public void onGetChildList(List<String> list) {
        // here your work with list
        //List<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
        obj = new HandleJSON(urlString);
        list = obj.fetchJSONChild(this);
    }
}
```

I have a method `fetchJSONChild()` like below:

```
List<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
           public void fetchJSONChild(final GetChildList callBack){
                final String[] str =  new String[3];
               // final List<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
               @Override
               public void run() {
               try {
                  URL url = new URL("http://192.168.x.xx:xxxx/childform_list/0.0.0.0/8069/new_db/admin/123456");
                  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                  conn.setReadTimeout(30000 /* milliseconds */);
                  conn.setConnectTimeout(50000 /* milliseconds */);
                  conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                  conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "GYUserAgentAndroid");
                  conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                  conn.setDoInput(true);
                  conn.setUseCaches (false);
                  // Starts the query
                  if (Build.VERSION.SDK != null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 13)
                  {
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close"); 
                  }
                  conn.connect();

                  System.out.println("Before url.openStream()");
               InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();//.openStream();
               System.out.println("After url.openStream()");
            String data = convertStreamToString(stream);
            // for example String data = "1,2,3";
            child.addAll(Arrays.asList(data.split(",")));

            readAndParseJSON(data);
            stream.close();
            callBack.onGetChildList(child);
               } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }
               }

             thread.start();

         }
```

And in this method thread is running and I want to get splitted string data that I put into the `list<string>` into my activity and below is my activity that I called `ChildActivity` :

```
package com.example.hakslogin;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.example.hakslogin.GetChildList;

public class ChildActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ListView lv_child;
    List<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
    Button btn_home;
    Button btn_add;
    private HandleJSON obj;
    public String urlString = "http://192.168.x.xx:xxxx/getdb";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_child);


        obj = new HandleJSON(urlString);
        obj.fetchJSONChild(null);
        lv_child = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_child); 
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, child);
        lv_child.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void onGetChildList(List<String> list) {
   //this method will be called after thread in fetchJSONChild ended
   child = list;
   lv_child = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_child); 
   String arr[]=child.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
   String[] Temp= new String[2];
          Temp[0] = arr[2].toString();
          array.add(Temp[0].split(":")[1]);
          String s = Temp[0].toString();
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
   lv_child.setAdapter(adapter);

}

}
```

I am getting exception `android.view.viewrootimpl$calledfromwrongthreadexception` when I populate `listview` from `list` on `onGetChildList` method in my `ChildActivity`.

Kindly suggest me, what I should waiting for reply.

Thanks

Comment: declare it as global variable

Comment: yes, I have declare list as a global variable and error is remove but when I debug my application and check variable value, its not show me any values like `1,2,3` after split.

Comment: That's the second part of the problem mentioned by Sufitruf below - as a thread is asynchronous, after exiting your method, the array is still empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `final` is mean that you will never change this variable. So you should use global variable or init it whith empty array and then fill it. Anyway, you have strange algorithm...

2) You start Thread. So all code inside it will be asynchronously. And your operation   `return child;` (in your case) always return null.

So, i recommend you to use callback for your thread cause it's assync operation...

Ok, thats how it's should look:

1) Declare interface:

```
public interface GetChildList{
        public void onGetChildList(List<String> list);
}
```

2) In you class (where you call `fetchJSONChild()`) implement it:

```
import com.example.hakslogin.GetChildList;

public class ChildActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements GetChildList {

    Button btn_home;
    Button btn_add;
    private HandleJSON obj;
    public String urlString = "http://192.168.x.xx:xxxx/getdb";

    List<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_child);


        obj = new HandleJSON(urlString);
        obj.fetchJSONChild(null);
        lv_child = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_child); 
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, child);
        lv_child.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
      public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        lv_child = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_child); 
         String arr[]=child.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
         String[] Temp= new String[2];
         Temp[0] = arr[2].toString();
         array.add(Temp[0].split(":")[1]);
         String s = Temp[0].toString();
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
         lv_child.setAdapter(adapter);
      };
   };



    @Override
    public void onGetChildList(List<String> list) {
       //this method will be called after thread in fetchJSONChild ended
       child = list;
       mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

    }
}
```

3) Your `fetchJSONChild` will something like this:

```
public void fetchJSONChild(final GetChildList callBack){

        final List<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {

                    URL url = new URL("http://192.168.x.xx:xxxx/childform_list/0.0.0.0/8069/new_db/admin/123456");
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setReadTimeout(30000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(50000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    //conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "GYUserAgentAndroid");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    //conn.setUseCaches (false);
                    // Starts the query
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK != null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 13) {

                        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close"); 
                    }
                    conn.connect();

                    System.out.println("Before url.openStream()");
                    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();//.openStream();
                    System.out.println("After url.openStream()");
                    String data = convertStreamToString(stream);
                    // for examole data = "1,2,3";

                    child.addAll(Arrays.asList(data.split(","));
                    readAndParseJSON(data);
                    stream.close();

                    callBack.onGetChildList(child);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start(); 
    }
```

4) in your class where you implemented `GetChildList` call `fetchJSONChild(this)`

5) After thread end working it will call `onGetChildList` where you can process you data.

Comment: @user3514596 you should import GetChildList in import section of file

Comment: @user3514596 you should't call fetchJSONChild(this) inside onGetChildList. onGetChildList method will call after fetchJSONChild ended

Comment: @user3514596 import yout_package.GetChildList;

Comment: @user3514596 you should import it in HandleJSON file too

Comment: I have edited my post, and try to make done what do you say but still getting errors, and I don't understand where I get my `list<string>` data i.e `1,2,3` that I called `child`. I am still confuse

Comment: @user3514596 check now

Comment: I am using these lines `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
         lv_child.setAdapter(adapter);` into another activity for populating `listview` through `adapter` but i am getting exception see this` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27249535/fatal-exception-main-android-java?noredirect=1#comment42974015_27249535`

Answer (score 0):

```
final List<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and replace

```
child = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data1.split(",")));
```

with

```
child.addAll(Arrays.asList(data1.split(","))
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted - it should fix the problem reported - although the list will still be empty when returned.

Answer (score 0):

This type of process which take time and work in background thread to not freeze the screen can't return the processing value. because, method will finish executing before the thread even start!! you start the thread. and when the result is ready in runOnUiThread you do whatever you want. like stop the loading icon and show data to user. that the concept.

```
List<String> child;
public void fetchJSONChild(){
         //= new ArrayList<String>();
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
       @Override
       public void run() {
       try {
          URL url = new URL("http://192.168.x.xx:xxxx/childform_list/0.0.0.0/8069/new_db/admin/123456");
          HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          conn.setReadTimeout(30000 /* milliseconds */);
          conn.setConnectTimeout(50000 /* milliseconds */);
          conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
          //conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "GYUserAgentAndroid");
          conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
          conn.setDoInput(true);
          //conn.setUseCaches (false);
          // Starts the query
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK != null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 13)
          {
           conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close"); 
          }
          conn.connect();

          System.out.println("Before url.openStream()");
       InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();//.openStream();
       System.out.println("After url.openStream()");
    String data = convertStreamToString(stream);
    // for examole data = "1,2,3";

    child = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data.split(","))); // <<<<---- data not data1!?
    readAndParseJSON(data);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // here you can update the ui with the child values.
                    for (int i=0;i<child.size();i++)
                         Log.e("Child", child.get(i));
                }
            });
       stream.close();

       } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
       }
    });

     thread.start();
 }
```

Note: this solution works perfectly if the method in the activity class. if not, please say so I can provide a proper solution.

Comment: how can i check `child2` have values or not for example `1,2,3` it should have .after splitted `String data`.

Comment: I got the problem. fixing it. wait

Comment: I have run your code but `child` is still empty, and i want to return `List<String> child;` and your piece of code not return `List<String> child;`.

Comment: Is this method exists in the activity class?

Comment: This type of process which take time and work in background thread to not freeze the screen can't return the processing value. because, method will finish executing before the thread even start!! you start the thread. and when the result is ready in runOnUiThread you do whatever you want. like stop the loading icon and show data to user. that the concept.

Comment: yes this method exist in the activity class. So Is there any way to get this list `List<String> child;` in the activity class.

Comment: ok, to explain more to you please edit your question to include the code you call the method from and include the code around it too.

Answer (score -1):

Remove `final` declaration of child and make it a global variable.

Comment: No, then he can't use it in the anonymous class.

Comment: for the record you cannot change a variable's value once it's declared as final.