# FATAL EXCEPTION: main android java

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I want to  populate `listview` through `adapter` using array like below:

```
public class ChildActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements GetChildList {

    private ListView lv_child;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_child);

        List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();   // for e.g array ["num1", "num2"]
        lv_child = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_child); 
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterChild = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ChildActivity.this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
        lv_child.setAdapter(adapterChild);

}
}
```

And its working fine but i am using the above the same code in another activity like below:

```
public class EmpListActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements GetEmployeeList {


    private ListView lv_employeeName;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_child);

            List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();   // for e.g array ["num3", "num4"]
            lv_employeeName = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_child); 
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapterEmployee= new ArrayAdapter<String>(EmpListActivity .this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
            lv_employeeName.setAdapter(adapterEmployee);

    }
    }
```

And in this activity I am getting below exceptions at this line `ArrayAdapter<String> adapterEmployee= new ArrayAdapter<String>(ChildActivity.this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);`

`FATAL EXCEPTION: main` and `java.lang.NullPointerException`

And also I want to ask, is there any problem for using the same `simple_list_item_1`  in the `adapter` parameter in both activity.

Kindly suggest me, waiting for reply.

Thanks

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: There is no problem at all. You can used Adapter separately.

Comment: Check your Imports for both class might conflict in that

Comment: I have already checked but the problem still comes