# where isimple_list_item_1 is declare in adapter parameters android java

Tags: java, android, listview, array-address

In android application  I am using `adapter` for populating `ListView` control like below:

```
public class ChildActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements GetChildList {

    private ListView lv_child;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_child);

        List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();   // for e.g array ["num1", "num2"]
        lv_child = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_child); 
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterChild = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ChildActivity.this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
        lv_child.setAdapter(adapterChild);

}
}
```

but i don't understand where its is `simple_list_item_1` declare at this line `ArrayAdapter<String> adapterChild = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ChildActivity.this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);`

Kindly suggest me, waiting for reply.

Comment: Android provides some standard list items, hence the android.R tag instead of your local resources from R. If you ctrl click it, it should show you the structure. You can also create your own xml and inflate that instead.

Comment: I have a problem at this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27249535/fatal-exception-main-android-java?noredirect=1#comment42974015_27249535`.  how can i resolve this issue, I am stuck up on it.

Comment: You seem to be passing an empty array of values there. You might just be better off writing your own adapter. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70 explains a bunch of cool stuff about it